# Best way to show terminal and cmd commands

Tags: formatting

I want to show terminal commands as well as command prompt commands (windows) and was wondering what is the best way to format these in latex.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}


\lstdefinestyle{DOS}
{
    backgroundcolor=\color{black},
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\color{white}\ttfamily
}

\begin{document}
Hi, I am Garbage Collector!
\begin{lstlisting}[style=DOS]
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

c:\User\Garbage Collector>
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice. I trust the `listings` package lets the user change the color scheme (as you can do in windows) for printing something other than white text on black.

Comment: @EthanBolker Yes it does.  I can just change the background color etc to get a nice looking terminal

Comment: Your screenshot made me smile. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda: Thank you :-) There is only one typo, `user` should be `users`. I left the typo intact to show that it is not the screenshot of `cmd`'s window. :-)

Comment: @GarbageCollector: Also the c above is lower case...it is actually upper case in cmd's window.

Comment: @GarbageCollector;  I was just saying that to again point out that your post isn't a screen shot.  It's further proof!